# Can anyone tell me what time point is and how to use it in this json response?

Tags: json, api

```
{ "product" : "astro" , "init" : "2020091906" , "dataseries" : [ { "timepoint" : 3, "cloudcover" : 7, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 3, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 6, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "S", "speed" : 2 }, "temp2m" : 33, "prec_type" : "rain" }, { "timepoint" : 6, "cloudcover" : 6, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 3, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 7, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "S", "speed" : 2 }, "temp2m" : 30, "prec_type" : "rain" }, { "timepoint" : 9, "cloudcover" : 1, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 3, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 7, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "SE", "speed" : 3 }, "temp2m" : 30, "prec_type" : "none" }, { "timepoint" : 12, "cloudcover" : 4, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 4, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 8, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "SE", "speed" : 2 }, "temp2m" : 29, "prec_type" : "none" }, { "timepoint" : 15, "cloudcover" : 2, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 4, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 9, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "E", "speed" : 2 }, "temp2m" : 29, "prec_type" : "none" }, { "timepoint" : 18, "cloudcover" : 3, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 4, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 8, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "E", "speed" : 2 }, "temp2m" : 29, "prec_type" : "rain" }, { "timepoint" : 21, "cloudcover" : 7, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 3, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 6, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "E", "speed" : 2 }, "temp2m" : 33, "prec_type" : "rain" }, { "timepoint" : 24, "cloudcover" : 8, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 3, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 5, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "SE", "speed" : 2 }, "temp2m" : 35, "prec_type" : "rain" }, { "timepoint" : 27, "cloudcover" : 9, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 3, "lifted_index" : -4, "rh2m" : 6, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "SW", "speed" : 3 }, "temp2m" : 32, "prec_type" : "rain" }, { "timepoint" : 30, "cloudcover" : 9, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 3, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 7, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "SW", "speed" : 3 }, "temp2m" : 30, "prec_type" : "rain" }, { "timepoint" : 33, "cloudcover" : 9, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 3, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 8, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "SW", "speed" : 2 }, "temp2m" : 30, "prec_type" : "none" }, { "timepoint" : 36, "cloudcover" : 9, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 4, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 9, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "W", "speed" : 2 }, "temp2m" : 29, "prec_type" : "none" }, { "timepoint" : 39, "cloudcover" : 6, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 4, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 9, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "N", "speed" : 2 }, "temp2m" : 28, "prec_type" : "rain" }, { "timepoint" : 42, "cloudcover" : 8, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 4, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 8, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "SW", "speed" : 2 }, "temp2m" : 29, "prec_type" : "rain" }, { "timepoint" : 45, "cloudcover" : 9, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 3, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 6, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "SE", "speed" : 2 }, "temp2m" : 32, "prec_type" : "rain" }, { "timepoint" : 48, "cloudcover" : 9, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 3, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 6, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "S", "speed" : 3 }, "temp2m" : 33, "prec_type" : "rain" }, { "timepoint" : 51, "cloudcover" : 9, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 3, "lifted_index" : -4, "rh2m" : 7, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "S", "speed" : 3 }, "temp2m" : 32, "prec_type" : "rain" }, { "timepoint" : 54, "cloudcover" : 7, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 4, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 9, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "S", "speed" : 3 }, "temp2m" : 30, "prec_type" : "rain" }, { "timepoint" : 57, "cloudcover" : 9, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 4, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 9, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "S", "speed" : 3 }, "temp2m" : 29, "prec_type" : "rain" }, { "timepoint" : 60, "cloudcover" : 9, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 5, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 10, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "S", "speed" : 3 }, "temp2m" : 28, "prec_type" : "rain" }, { "timepoint" : 63, "cloudcover" : 9, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 5, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 10, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "SE", "speed" : 2 }, "temp2m" : 28, "prec_type" : "rain" }, { "timepoint" : 66, "cloudcover" : 8, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 4, "lifted_index" : -1, "rh2m" : 9, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "SE", "speed" : 2 }, "temp2m" : 29, "prec_type" : "rain" }, { "timepoint" : 69, "cloudcover" : 9, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 4, "lifted_index" : -4, "rh2m" : 7, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "SE", "speed" : 2 }, "temp2m" : 31, "prec_type" : "rain" }, { "timepoint" : 72, "cloudcover" : 9, "seeing" : 6, "transparency" : 3, "lifted_index" : -4, "rh2m" : 7, "wind10m" : { "direction" : "SW", "speed" : 2 }, "temp2m" : 32, "prec_type" : "rain" } ] }
```

Their documentation is here: http://www.7timer.info/doc.php?lang=en#introduction
It says nothing about what the timepoint is, what it represents, or how to use it.
Any help here is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 8):

It seems to be an old question but I think i have got the answer to that. Perhaps someone else is thankfull for that.

First you'll see the init date. It stands for the date and time when the forecast was made. In you example it was 2020-09-19 at 6:OO AM .
From this time/date you have to add the timepoint from the forecast. For example timepoint 3 means 9:00 AM and timepoint 6 means 12:00 AM.

Comment: I might come back to work on this project in the near future, so I appreciate your response still!

Comment: And what about "timepoint": 114, for example? Or "timepoint": 198? Adding it to the time doesn't make any sense. By the way, the last two digits of init field don't correlate with time. The time can be found in the comment above: // 20211128230242, the last 6 digits.

Answer (score 1):

The "timepoint" variable is hours past the "init" time. In your example: "init": "2020091906" corresponds to 2020-09-19 at 6 AM. At "timepoint": 3, that is 9 AM, and it goes up to 72 hours after that init datetime. It is the same thing on the METEO forecast, too, but that one is 192 hours.